# Does an object's size affect performance?

Tags: perl

Working on a relatively big old Perl application which uses some OOP concepts.

I wondered if the size of the created objects affects the performance of the product.

If it does, would it improve the performance if I split the objects (which are currently big) into multiple smaller modules unreferenced at the proper time?

The object is defined here with the following structure and then exported to be available in other modules.

```
# module FilesModule.pm
use Exporter   ();
our ($VERSION, @ISA, @EXPORT);
# set the version for version checking
$VERSION     = 6.00;
@ISA         = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT      = qw($FilesModule);
}

sub new {
    my $className = shift;
    my $self = {
        txtFilesList => "array with all files stored in a folder",
        testFilesList => "array with all files that need to be tested",
        filesListToDelete => "array with all files to be deleted",
        logFiles => "array with all log files",
    };

    bless $self, $className;
}
```

The main module makes an instance of the object and then uses it ( also the object is used later in another modules)

```
#module MainModule.pm
use modules::FilesModule qw($FilesModule);

#create the files object
my $FilesModule = modules::FilesModule->new(...);

# iterate over txtFilesList array
# iterate over testFilesList array and do some tests in file and remove from object the failed subjects
# iterate over filesListToDelete array and delete the files
# iterate over logFiles array and change the extensions ( also change in object)
```

My thought would be to split the FilesModule.pm in 4 modules to have smaller objects to work with.

Comment: The larger an object is, the more time it takes to load into memory/cache, the more size it uses in the cache (and thus less objects can be placed into cache). So yes, object size has an impact.

Comment: Mind that the above comment makes the assumption you create an object and work on it. Accessing a *single* member of the object has no such impact.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The impact is worth enough to consider a redesign? Take an example where my object stores 2 arrays with 1000 elements each which is loaded for 2 operations. Would it be worth to split the object in 2 objects one for each operation?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I think that is misleading. In general, objects are *created*, and nor "loaded into memory". The OP's suggestion of dividing the object into multiple smaller ones won't affect the total size, and so won't improve the time to create the data.

Comment: @Borodin: see my second comment. It is only if you *work* on larger objects that this indeed slows down things.

Comment: @asdf: We would really have to see your code, and your question really belongs on [**Code Review**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Borodin I made an update with some code that emulates the functionality and the scenario.

Comment: So those are filenames, not full files, right? How many are we talking? Hundreds, thousands, tens of thousands? How many of those objects do you make? How many are in memory at once? I think you are trying to find a problem where there is none. If performance is a problem, it might well be because the code uses the data in a slow way. I suggest you run it with Devel::NYTProf and look at things that appear slow there. Likely it's not how your data is organized, but how it's created or used.

Comment: @simbabque File names, not full paths, 1000 on each array maximum. I make only one object and keep it in memory from the begining to the end, I will try to do this at home to install the profiler module ( currently I can't pass the company proxy)

Comment: That's really not a lot of data. What typically slows things down if you have Moose or Moo, and **a lot** of small objects that get created and destroyed all the time. Think reading a product list and creating several different objects per line, with files larger than 100k rows. In that case, it's visible that all the object stuff is on top of existing data structures. But the use-case you are describing sounds trivial. Internally, an object is no different from any other reference, it just as a bit of meta info attached through the `bless`.

Comment: Is there a performance concern that is based on a real observation, or is this all just a hypothetical question? If you feel that your application is not performant have you profiled it to see where the time is being spent?  See `Devel::NYTProf` for a profiling solution.  See `Benchmark` for a module that helps test alternative solutions.

Comment: @DavidO Just hypotethical. The application execution takes about 10 minutes and I was wondering ( if you check the question title) if it's the objects sizes a concern that I should take in account.

Comment: @DavidO Basically I am concerned that I am using a big object instead of smaller ones and that is affecting the performance

Comment: By what you describe the size should not be your problem.  Now, there may be other _related_ problems.  Say, in every operation you delete file names from your lists and repopulate others.  _That_ would be slow, since deleting from an array is horrible, and rewriting whole arrrays all the time just takes time.  But that's not about size per se. I'd say, profile as others have said, then take it from there.  You may indeed want to restructure your class, but not merely because of size.